# Creating Subscription through Postman throws error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Creating WebHook for MicrosoftGraph throws error

What is ClientState represents ?

```
{
    "changeType": "updated",
    "clientState": "kT]G=3@hClz0rRfOuVr*3UA8V_9UGs4p",
    "expirationDateTime": "2019-09-26T15:46:18.835Z",
    "notificationUrl": "https://webhooksformicrosoftgraph.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger1",
    "resource": "groups"
}

{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidRequest",
    "message": "Subscription validation request failed. Must respond with 200 OK to this request.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "4f368e23-9a5d-4c72-a2cf-9bbe33f677f4",
      "date": "2019-09-23T06:35:20"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We have a great tutorial on setting up your first change notification (web hook). You may want to run through this first

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/change-notifications

Basically your API that our web hook calls needs to return 200 OK on first registering a subscription for our service to validate your API.